# Joomla 2.5.7 editing text item under an image on homepage

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Joomla 2.5.7 editing text item under an image on homepage

hi , 
I'm new to Joomla and I need to edit text under a logo on our home page. How or where can I do this. I am using Joomla 2.5.7

thanks!

Comment: First of all you need to update, that's not just unsupported it's way before the last supported version.  Second, you're really asking about how to use the tool not how to code. So you really need to read the beginner documentation and maybe visit the joomla.stackexchange.com site or the joomla.org site.  In the meantime, you haven't given enough information to answer the question.  No one can tell what the text is or where it came from using your description.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Agree I wanted to add a screenshot to show what I meant, but I was not allowed to, it's not code but I love this forum and I know I can always be pointed in the right direction here when I post questions. i tried searching already via joomla forum and could not find anything related to it. I will keep trying.

Comment: Is the text in a module or is it part of the template or is it from an article?

Comment: The text could possibly be a parameter for the template you're using, in the Template Manager. Without knowing which template you're using or possibly a link to your site, it's going to be rather hard to tell where this text is coming from. As @Elin has already said though, please update to the latest version of the 2.5 series (2.5.28)

Comment: we found where to change this it was managed in the template and our developer is now adjusting it.

Comment: we are also recommending the upgrade too - thanks for the advice here. always great!

Comment: @Charlotte - Please would you mind posting the solution as an answer and mark it as solved, so other users are aware ;)